# How to send a device management request using NodeRed or any REST client

Tags: post, ibm-cloud, node-red, watson-iot

I am trying to sent a DM firmware update command from a NodeRed Flow.

Function node:

```
msg.payload = {"MgmtInitiationRequest": {
"action":"firmware/update",
"devices": [{
"typeId": "myType",
"deviceId": "myDevice"
}]

}}
msg.headers={"Content-Type":"application/json"}
return msg;
```

I send it to a http request node with a POST to

```
https://orgid.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/api/v0002/mgmt/requests
```

Basic Authentication with api keys.  I based it of [Initiate a device management request](https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#!/Device_Management_Requests/post_mgmt_requests)

I get back a **403** which the docs have as:

> One or more of the devices does not support the requested action

Anyone see what I'm missing?  It works fine from the IoT Platform UI to the same devicetype/deviceid.

EDIT: Same 403 if I use a Rest client like Postman.

Comment: AFAIK your NR flow will have to be connected as an application to send a dm command - is that the case?

Comment: @barny Yes, it's using api keys so should be connecting as an application

Comment: The docs show the parameter being called deviceManagementInitiationRequest rather than MgmtInitiationRequest - some reason for not using the name the docs show? Does a "device/reboot" action work?

Comment: Because the Model on the right has MgmtInitiationRequest.  But I see what you mean, and tried with deviceManagementInitiationRequest and with device/reboot and still get that bleed'n 403. Also dropped that part totally (as it is going to a mgmt endpoint).

Comment: @barny I moved out of NR to Postman and same 403.  I think I'm not understanding how exactly the body should be, and if any other headers.  Can't follow that swagger doc.  Or it's wrong.

Comment: If, hypothetically, you used e.g. Fiddler to spy on IoTP UI/browser networking you may see the correct syntax for the REST POST, if it is done from the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The swagger API documentation is a little bit misleading in that the 'body' parameter is given a name.
But, like the other POST APIs, that name isn't actually included anywhere as part of the payload.

The payload should just look like this:

```
{
    "action": "firmware/update",
    "devices": [
        {
            "typeId": "string",
            "deviceId": "string"
        }
    ]
}
```

This page in the documentation provides more detail:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/devices/device_mgmt/requests.html#firmware-actions-update

Comment: I had tried that also, tried it again.  But I'm still getting 403.  Generated new api keys, just in case... Do you know if standard Application's ok for them or do I need something else?

Comment: Do you already have an in-progress firmware update request for the specified device? There is only 1 firmware update in-progress allowed at a time for a particular device.

Also, can you verify with this request that your device does claim support for firmware actions?
GET /api/v0002/device/types/myType/devices/myDevice/mgmt

Comment: No, they are completed.  I get this back for the GET: {
  "supports": {
    "deviceActions": true,
    "firmwareActions": true
  },
  "dormant": false,
  "firmware": {
    "version": "",
    "name": "",
    "verifier": "",
    "state": "0",
    "updateStatus": "0"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Has your appliance published the set of supported commands it supports when it announced itself **as a managed device**?

*A device connects to the Watson IoT Platform and uses the **managed devices operation to become a managed device**.*

Which looks something like this

Topic: iotdevice-1/mgmt/manage

{
...
        "supports": {
            **"deviceActions": true,
            "firmwareActions": boolean**
        },
...
    },
...
}

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/devices/device_mgmt/index.html

Comment: I believe so, and that I've done it correctly because if I go to the IoT Platform and Initiate Action there, the Download/Update Firmware actions work.  I suspect I'm not understanding that swagger doc correctly to do it as a REST call.  I keep modifying it but no joy yet.  Less hair on head.